# How can I stop Full screen video after I resize it?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, xcode4, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I try to resize video with Pinch Gesture. But after I pinch and animate resizing , video get to full screen that I dont want. 
How can I stop full screen ??

take a look at my code and Please to help me

```
{
    NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video1" ofType:@"MOV"];
        movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];
        movie.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        movie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
        movie.shouldAutoplay = YES;


    movie.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 720, 1280);
    [self.view addSubview:movie.view];
    [movie play];

    // -----------------------------------
    // Add BlockView for block user touch
    // -----------------------------------
    blockView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 760, 1280);
    blockView.alpha = 0.2;
    [self.view addSubview:blockView];

    // -----------------------------
    // Add Pinch Gesture
        // -----------------------------
        UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchIt = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchIn:)];
        [self.blockView addGestureRecognizer:pinchIt];
 }  




-(void)pinchIn:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognize
{
    [movie pause];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];

    movie.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [movie setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];
    //movie.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 150, 360, 640);  << Have try this but didnt work
    [movie play];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to run fine. Try setting the center first.
  movie.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size. height/2);